# Performing multiple segues programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I've three view controllers in my app. I want to switch between them using buttons in my navigation bar (leftBarButton for my first ViewController, central - for second and rightBarButton for third Controller). Because I want my app to ajust my buttons based on the device screen size I need to set them programmatically.

I've created segues from each Controller and tried to connect them to my UIViewController classes.

Here is the code (where I add functions and buttons) of the first ViewController:

```
func openExp(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openPubExp", sender: sender)
}

func openElse(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openPubElse", sender: sender)
}
```

My ViewDidLoad:

```
var navBarImage: UIImage? = nil
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375.0 {
        navBarImage = UIImage(named: "publications@2xiphone6.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
    }
    else {
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414.0 {
            navBarImage = UIImage(named: "publications@3x.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        }
        else {
            navBarImage = UIImage(named: "publications@2x.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))

            let button1 = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Moroz.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)

            button1.addTarget(self, action: "openExp:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton1


            let button2 = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "Moroz.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)

            button2.addTarget(self, action: "openElse:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button2)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton2


        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

The code is the same for my other ViewControllers. Just names of my functions and segues is different. I can switch between my first and second ViewController.

The problem is that whenever I try to access my third ViewController I get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Code for my third ViewController:

```
var myFeed : NSArray = []
var url: NSURL = NSURL()


@IBOutlet weak var centalPB: UIButton!

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ,UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self




    url = NSURL(string: "http://194.186.62.58/AppWebservice/Services.asmx/getOtherNews")!

    loadRss(url);

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.title = ""
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Назад"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    var navBarImage: UIImage? = nil
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375.0 {
        navBarImage = UIImage(named: "else@2xiphone6.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
    }
    else {
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414.0 {
            navBarImage = UIImage(named: "else@3x.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        }
        else {
            navBarImage = UIImage(named: "else@2x.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))

            let button1 = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Moroz.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 40)

            button1.addTarget(self, action: "openElse:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton1

            self.centalPB.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 50)
            self.centalPB.setImage(UIImage(named: "Moroz.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.centalPB.addTarget(self, action: "openPublic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
}


func loadRss(data: NSURL) {

    let myParser = XmlParserManager(URL: data)

    myFeed = myParser.feeds

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



    if segue.identifier == "openPage2" {

        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedFTitle: String = myFeed[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Title") as! String
        let selectedFContent: String = myFeed[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Description") as! String

        // Instance of our feedpageviewcontrolelr
        let fpvc: ElseViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ElseViewController

        fpvc.selectedFeedTitle = selectedFTitle
        fpvc.selectedFeedFeedContent = selectedFContent
    }
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myFeed.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellElse

    let chevron = UIImage(named: "Next4.png")
    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: chevron!)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Feeds dictionary.
    var dict : NSDictionary! = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    cell.titleLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Title") as? String
    cell.descLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Description") as? String
    cell.dateLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Date_text") as? String

    return cell

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

There was no errors if I just use my storyboards but in that case I can't ajust the size of my buttons.

UPDATE:

```
ElseTableViewController 0x7ae5dff0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key centralEB.'
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using containerview

Comment: Can you please add the full stacktrace of exception?

Comment: so you can't access to third VC from second and from the first one right?

Comment: @iphonic updated my main post

Comment: @wm.p1us that's right, yes.

Comment: The Problem is your Xib itself, right on the xib in storyboard, and remove any connection with yellow warning icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by linking from storyboard to a property that doesn't exist. 
Check all the connections from your third VC in the storyboard to your code file because it happens when you try to load it.

Try to remember if you change any name of the property or method by the way? If yes check if you renew connection or not.

Comment: Yes, I double checked it. It seems that my storyboard was always one step behind my code. Whenever I changed the name of my property, the storyboard tried to call my button by its previous name. So I deleted this button and the connection to my class and recreated it under a new name. Now all works fine. Thank you!